# Parallel aync await instead of Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Take a look at the below code, it uses `async` and `await` to execute a list of `promises`. But they will execute sequentially meaning once `promises[0]` resolves then only the execution of `promises[1]` starts.

I want to fire all the promises in parallel and wait for them together. I know we can do this using `Promise.all` but how can we do it using just `await` and `async` ?

```
// An array of promises
let promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.reject("error"),
  Promise.resolve(2),
];

// An async function that uses a for loop
async function useForLoop() {
  try {
    // Declare an empty array to store the results
    let results = [];
    // Use a for loop to iterate over the promises
    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
      // Use await to pause the execution until the current promise is resolved
      let result = await promises[i];
      // Push the result to the array
      results.push(result);
    }
    // Log the results
    console.log(results); // [1, 2]
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any error from the promises
    console.error(error); // "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I know we can do this using Promise.all"* - That's indeed how to await an array of Promises.  Why can't you use that here?

Comment: It's just in my code base we mostly use async/await as a replacement for Promise chaining. So wanted to know if there is a way I can do this using async/await instead of Promise.all

Comment: You can't do it using just `async` and `await`. The whole point of `await` is to make an async call appear to be synchronous.

Comment: @insanely_sin: *"using async/await instead of Promise.all"* - So... Using Promises instead of using Promises?  It's not really clear what you're trying to describe.  You can `await` a call to `Promise.all`.  I really don't see a reason to not use the right tool for the job here.  I suppose another option could be to write your own `Promise.all` implementation, which doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @insanely_sin You can use `await` instead of `.then()`. But `Promise.all` does not do any "promise chaining", so you still should (need to!) use it.

Comment: "*they will execute sequentially meaning once `promises[0]` resolves then only the execution of `promises[1]` starts.*" - no they don't! Promises do not "execute". They are objects representing asynchronous *results*, not tasks. The "execution" starts right when you create them in `let promises` (though your code doesn't actually *do* anything, it creates immediately settled promises).

Comment: I see, thanks all, gonna `await` on  `Promise.all([...])`